# Obsolete and/or deprecated JavaScript code using a current Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, vb.net-2010, firefox-browser-api

I am supporting a vb.net 2010 web form .net application and I have found out that some of the JavaScript has been deprecated using Internet Explorer by using the Internet Explorer web developer tools. I have now used the Firefox browser and the application seems to work for what I have tested so far.

Before I place the new version of the application into production, I would like to know what JavaScript features are currently obsolete and/or may be deprecated in the near future.

Due to that fact, would you tell me and/or point me to urls (links) that will tell me what JavaScript items are obsolete and/or deprecated using the Firefox browser?

Comment: Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/).

Comment: To be more specific: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features

Comment: As a sidenote, asking for documentation links is usually not welcome on SO, especially since most of the time people will just link you back to... MDN and CanIUse :)

Comment: Thank you very much! That answers my question!